# Logical AND for Conditional Formatting in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have been doing a lot of research regarding this but it seems my formula is not working. I was trying to check two cells. One cell should not be empty and another cell should be less than or equal zero and what it does is it changes the color of the text of a certain cell.

*Please see picture below for reference.*

I have an existing conditional formatting which checks D5:D29 if it's not empty and changes the color of E5:E31 to Blue. 
See formula : `=NOT(ISBLANK(D5:D29))` - this is working great.

**Problem:**
I'm going to check cell D5:D29 if it's not empty and I'm going to check E5:E31 if it's less than or equal to zero. If both are TRUE, the color of the text in E5:E31 changes to red. 
Formula : `=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(D5:D29)),(E5:E31<=0))`
Please see picture below. My formula is not working. Is there something wrong in it?

[image: Picture]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What's wrong with my formula?

Comment: Nothing. It works for me. Add more details, some screenshots will be helpful.

Comment: Please see edited post.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

The problem is on the references being used.

Instead of D5:D29 and E5:E31 use D5 and E5 when to the conditional formatting formula applied to E5:31

## Explanation

Conditional formatting formulas applied to a range of cells, should be written having in mind the top-left cell. The spreadsheet engine will "automatically adjust" the formula for the other cells in the range.